# RecyclerView - release of long press does not reset foreground drawable state

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use views in my `RecyclerView` with a selector like following:

```
 android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
```

Then, in my adapter, I set click and long press listeners like following:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // handle click
        }
    });
itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // handle long click
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The problem is, the selector stays in pressed state after a long press(ONLY after a long press!) until I click somewhere else or similar (clicking another view, scrolling, ...)... Clicking works perfectly fine...

Any idea what can cause such a behaviour?

Comment: What if you return false? Might be a bug.

Comment: Tried that as well already, still the same behaviour...